# Emulation of event-driven design in Cloud Run while developing locally?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, event-driven

I'm developing an application with microservice architecture running on Google Cloud Run  (fully managed). I want to add communication over events to my services. As I know, the only option is to use Eventarc. I'm curious what is the best way to reproduce the event-driven design when developing locally and how to make deployment as seamless as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Google cloud explicitly, but I assume they all work similarly. As long as you can get your code running locally, then you can still use the cloud hosted message queue / pub/sub interface from your local code.

This way you can debug and try things out on your local machine while still using the messaging / eventing infrastructure.